# Lit-element and webpack

Tags: webpack, lit-element

Is there a way to make webpack works with lit-element WebComponents? Searching around I've found some sample webpack configuration with little to nothing real-world usage. For example how can I make webpack `file-loader` or `html-loader` recognize my images?
If I have the following configuration

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
      main: "./src/index.js",
    },
    module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: ["html-loader"]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
                        esModule: false,
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

both loaders won't recognize the html template inside the webcomponent and they won't process it as html. Is there a way make webpack replaces my images assets with what `file-loader` tells to?

Minimal sample code:

**index.html**

```
<body>
This is an image outside a webcomponent <img src="./assets/polymer-logo.jpg" />
<my-element></my-element>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`
      This image is inside a web component:
      <img src="./assets/polymer-logo.jpg" />
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to import the images? Can you show some code? Also, what do you mean by `won't recognize the html template inside the webcomponent`? That is not an `.html` file so it won't be loaded at all...

Comment: I've added some code to the question. Of course I'm not asking why it doesn't work, it doesn't suppose to, as you said it's not an .html. How can I make it work? What's the common way in webpack to handle images in WebComponents?

Answer (score 2):

The loaders only affect the behavior of JS imports, i.e. `html-loader` will come into play only when the bundler finds an .html import:

```js
import html from './file.html';
```

(from Webpack's html-loader [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/)).

The same goes for `file-loader`:

```js
import image from './image.png'; // This instructs Webpack to emit the
                                 // asset into the output directory
                                 // and returns the public URL...

class MyElement extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      This image is inside a web component:
      <img src=${image} /> <!-- ...that you can set as the src -->
    `;
  }

}
```

As for the template, it actually depends on what you mean by "process it as html":
if you want to load it from an external html file I don't think there is currently an easy way to do that with bundlers; if you want to minify it, there is a [babel plugin](https://github.com/cfware/babel-plugin-template-html-minifier) that allows for that. Also, there are some Webpack loaders made for lit-element you may be interested in: [lit-scss-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-scss-loader), [lit-loader](https://github.com/PolymerX/lit-loader).

You may want to take a look at the [Webpack section](https://open-wc.org/building/building-webpack.html#configuration) of the Open WebComponents guide for some good recommendations and base wp configurations.